# Can @Before and/or @After methods inspect the expected parameter?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Part of a test fixture checks that no errors were logged during a test:

```
@After
public void testname() {
    if(accumulatedErrors()) {
        fail("Errors were recorded during test");
    }
}
```

But for a test that is expected to fail, like this:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
public void shouldExplode() throws Exception {
    doExplodingStuff();
}
```

the @After method should invert the check:

```
@After
public void testname() {
    if (failureIsExpected()) {
        assertTrue("No errors were recorded during test", accumulatedErrors());
    } else {
        assertFalse("Errors were recorded during test", accumulatedErrors());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to inspect the `expected` parameter of the executed test from the `@After` method?

Of course, the test could specify `expectToFail=true` or something like that, but I would like to avoid that duplication.

Comment: Did you have a look at the JUnit's [ErrorCollector Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules#errorcollector-rule) and [ExpectedException Rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules#expectedexception-rules)?

Answer (score 2):

Why you cannot add `assertTrue` or `assertFalse` in each test method ?
You solution seems to me too complicated.
Method annotated with `@After` should be used to release resources.

Comment: The @After method is used to assert that no errors recorded (or logged), which would otherwise be added to every test.

Comment: Asserting in after / before method is bad : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707544/is-assert-ing-on-teardown-after-method-wrong>

Comment: It is normal solution to have assertion at the end of test method. If test fail then you can quickly check which assert was bad.

Answer (score 0):

Using [catch-exception](http://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/), you can move the check for an exception inside the method instead of outside the method:

```
@Test
public void shouldExplode() throws Exception {
    catchException(this).doExplodingStuff();
    assertTrue(caughtException() instanceof IllegalStateException);
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that the @After method will fail later.

Comment: @Markus you mean you want a soft assertion that will not terminate the test case? If that is the case, you already have some sort of non-fatal `checkTrue` method you can substitute the `assertTrue` above with.

Comment: No, the test case should fail if an error was logged. Unless we expect the test to throw an exception, then the test would fail if no error was logged.

Comment: @Markus hm, but the test above does fail when `doExplodingStuff` does not throw?